# How to set up property in Java hibernate configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate

I currently have hibernate bean set up in an legacy package that is using XML:

```
<bean name="returnsDao" class="com.mycompany.HibernateReturnsDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="myhqSessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="myhqSessionFactory" name="myhqSessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="myDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <ref bean="myHibernateProperties" />
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.HibernateReturnsDAO</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How do I create the beans in Java configuration from another package? I am trying to use the legacy package and my current package use Java config to initialize beans.

I tried the following and I am getting NPE at `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, I suspect the Java config didn't set the `property` attribute properly, but how do I set up in Java config?

```
@Bean
public HibernateReturnsDAO returnDAO() {
    return new HibernateReturnsDAO();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Hibernate documentation for [programmatic configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)